# jQueryUI icons are always shown on the top instead of inline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I wanted to create some buttons using jQueryUI with some icons for a better style. My problem is that the icons are always shown on the top of the button-text. Is there a possibility to show the icons always inline with the text?

HTML

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button><sub class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick ui-btn-icon-left"></sub>Delete Result</button>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
$( "input[type=submit], a, button" )
.button()
.click(function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

Here is also a link to jsfiddle with the code so that you can imagine what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/14sxbj59/

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.ui-icon` class has `display: block` styling enabled by default.

You will need to change that to an `inline-block` in order for it to work. For this example, I used the `.ui-btn-icon-left` class you created.

```
.ui-btn-icon-left
{
    display: inline-block;  
    margin: 0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/14sxbj59/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Add following with your code:

```
.ui-state-default .ui-icon {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/14sxbj59/3/).